# FlashDevelop. Error "Is not a valid ANE file"

Tags: android, air, flashdevelop, air-native-extension, ane

I really need your help.

I created my own native extension (Android) and added it to the project. But when the PackageApp.bat runs it constantly displays this error:
"Is not a valid ANE file"

At the same time, the same happens with some of other third-party extensions (Flurry ANE (com.freshplanet.AirFlurry) works normally for example, but another Flurry (com.sticksports.nativeExtensions.Flurry) doesn't).

I looked for solution everywhere, but could not find any answers. Please, help me with this had pain :)

---

Here is the link to the ANE.

8b.kz/V7To

---

Making ANE (Windows):

adt -package -target ane SampleASExtension.ane extension.xml -swc ANESample.swc -platform Android-ARM -C Android-ARM .

---

Folder structure:

- Android-ARM 
  ----- ANESample.jar 
  ----- library.swf
- ANESample.swc
- extension.xml

---

Extension.xml:

```html
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/15.0">
  <id>com.adobe.sampleasextension</id>
  <name>Android App Expansion AIR Extension</name> 
  <description>Allow AIR applications for Android to break the 50mb limit and use expansion files.</description> 
  <copyright>Copyright (c) 2011 - 2013 Alessandro Bianco</copyright> <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber> 
  <platforms> 
    <platform name="Android-ARM"> 
      <applicationDeployment> 
      <nativeLibrary>ANESample.jar</nativeLibrary> 
      <initializer>com.adobe.sampleasextension.ANESample</initializer> 
      <finalizer>com.adobe.sampleasextension.ANESample</finalizer> 
      </applicationDeployment> 
    </platform> 
  </platforms> 
</extension>
```

Comment: Please format your xml in a code block.

Comment: @Magnilex Done, sorry